# Pagination missing in Magento 2.1.9 category pages

Tags: magento2, pagination, magento-2.1.9

I've reviewed similar posts about this topic but none seem affiliated. It seems like after I disabled a few products that pagination disappeared. I also cant see pagination options in the backend at

> stores > configuration > general > design

Comment: Did you solve the issue?. I've the same

Answer (score 0):

Please check below setting.

> stores > configuration > catalog > catalog > store front > products per page

This configuration will allow you to set products per in **Grid** and **List** Mode.

Comment: I don't see where I can affect pagination there. I can set products per page but I can't  go to the next page.

Comment: what are the setting in your Admin and how many products are showing on listing page.

Comment: There are over 100 products in some categories. Pagination doesn't show.

Comment: Did you solve that issue?